# By default no column is showed in kendo grid and when i select column from ColumnMenu then only show data in grid for selected column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

Here is my Grid Code

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<VendorModel>()
    .Name("grid").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height:600px;"  })
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        
        columns.Bound(p => p.VendorCode).Title("Vendor Code").Width(150).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.VendorName).Title("Vendor Name").Width(250).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.BuyerName).Title("Buyer Name").Width(150).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.CommodityCode).Title("Commodity Code").Width(200).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" });
         
        columns.Bound(p => p.IncludeInReport).Title("Include In report").Width(180).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" });
        
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
             toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn btn-info" });
             toolbar.Custom().Text("Download Template").Name("Vtemplate").Action("DownloadVendorBlank_Templates", "Setting").HtmlAttributes(new { Id = "Vtemplate", title = "Download Template for importing data through excel", @class = "btn btn-info" });
             toolbar.Custom().Text("Import Excel").Name("ImportVendor").HtmlAttributes(new { Id = "ImportVendor", title = "Import vendor throug excel", @class = "btn btn-info" });
            
        })
     .Excel(excel => excel
                .FileName("Vendors.xlsx")
                .Filterable(true)
               
            )
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
     .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
    
    .Scrollable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
   
    .Resizable(m => m.Columns(true))
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Reorderable(m => m.Columns(true))
    
   .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
     
    .Read(read => read.Action("Vendor_Read", "Setting"))
     
    )
    )
```

Grid have 5 column. But i want by default only 3 column to show and when i click on checkbox in ColumnMenu => Column filter then only checked column should be displayed.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

By default hiding/ (dont show) column in grid then you have to set .Hidden(true) at each column.

> i.e-  columns.Bound(c =>
>   c.Country).Title("Country").Width(150)**.Hidden(true);**

And when you see check box list in Column Menu filter from there you can again select that column as view in grid.